# Developer Name: Android App Transfer to Another account

Tags: android, google-play

I followed this [checklist](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en) and my App transfer was successful.

I got following message from Google Play Team

```
Hi, Your transfer is complete! Thanks for providing the necessary info for your application transfer. Thanks for supporting Google Play!
```

When I access my App link, its still showing my Original Account Developer Name and not the Target Account Developer Name. Any solutions??

Answer (score 1):

Transferring an application does not transfer account information. You **can** [change](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113467?hl=en) your Developer Name though. I imagine Developer Names need to be unique, so the change may not be as smooth as a single step. You may need to change the Target's Developer Name to something else in order to take it for yourself.